# Testando um cron-job com JEST

Tags: javascript, node.js, testes, cron, jest

Eu tenho uma classe javascript que contém uma função a qual inicializa um cron job. Para realizar o cron-job fiz uso da biblioteca Node-Cron. Porém não consigo encontrar uma forma de testar a classe e a função.

As variáveis que controlam o node-cron estão em um .env.
Para os testes estou utilizando jest
O Job é startado quando a aplicação é levantada(o arquivo que contém a classe é importado e a classe já é exportada instanciada)

**.env file**

```
#CRON JOB
FREQUENCY_CRON='30 00 * * *'
TIMEZONE="America/Sao_Paulo"
SCHEDULED=true
INACTIVE_EXPIRATION_TIME=2592000000 #30 DAYS
```

**CronJob.js**

```
class CronJob {
  constructor() {
    this.startJob();
  }

  async startJob() {
    cron.schedule(
      process.env.FREQUENCY_CRON,
      async () => {
        //DO SOME DATA PROCESSING 
      },
      {
        scheduled: process.env.SCHEDULED,
        timezone: process.env.TIMEZONE
      }
    );
  }
}

export default new CronJob();
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma das melhores formas para isolar o escopo de uma unidade de código é utilizar injeção de dependências, assim você consegue simular diferentes casos de testes sem precisar de muita configuração, no seu caso ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```js
// importante exportar a classe também para permitir criar 
// uma instancia passando configurações, diferente do export default
export class CronJob {
  // o parâmetro configurations por padrão é um objeto vazio para permitir 
  // acessar as propriedades mesmo quando não há configurações, evitando o erro
  // "cannot read property of undefined"
  constructor(configurations = {}) {
    // o valor após o operador || é o padrão quando a configuração está ausente
    this.frequencyCron = configurations.frequencyCron || process.env.FREQUENCY_CRON;
    this.scheduled = configurations.scheduled || process.env.SCHEDULED;
    this.timezone = configurations.timezone || process.env.TIMEZONE;
    this.startJob();
  }

  async startJob() {
    cron.schedule(
      this.frequencyCron,
      async () => {
        //DO SOME DATA PROCESSING 
      },
      {
        scheduled: this.scheduled,
        timezone: this.timezone
      }
    );
  }
}

export default new CronJob();
```

Dessa forma, nos testes você consegue instanciar um novo CronJob com as configurações que você achar mais adequadas para cada caso específico, exemplo:

```
new CronJob({
  timezone: 'America/New_York'
})
```